# Crew launched to comet where contact with organism starts their metamorphosis

Tags: story-identification

Contemporary time period.  At the start, the crew is being launched (by NASA?) to rendezvous with a comet.  An X15 is launched at the same time to try to stop them, but fails.  Mission makes it to comet but find organisms cause some to metamorphosis.  Earth politics start a disaster.  Seem to remember the cover looking like an Apollo capsule

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You mentioned a cover, so just to be clear, is this a novel? And if so, in roughly which year did you read it?

Comment: Was it Halley's Comet?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi You're probably thinking of the same story I am.

Comment: @DavidW I was thinking about Heart of the Comet by David Brin, but it's plot is a bit in the future.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi That was my exact thought too. :)

Comment: Also there is no X-15 in *Heart of the Comet*. Rick, are you sure about the X-15? It doesn't seem a likely way to intercept a mission headed out to a comet.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the X-15 this is probably a blurry memory of Stephen Baxter's *[Titan](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9447)*.

In this incredibly dumb book, the USAF hates the shuttle program so much, that when NASA launches a shuttle mission to Saturn (don't ask), they get an X-15 out of the museum and try to use it to shoot down the shuttle during its launch.

I threw the book against the wall after this episode, but the plot summary in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(Baxter_novel)) does mention global disaster, Earth politics, and the crew being transformed "through some unspecified alien process".

Comment: Other answers that may have corroborating details [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253822/i-am-looking-for-a-book-about-four-or-five-people-leaving-earth/253855#253855) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265135/novel-with-a-modified-space-shuttle-seeding-a-colony-on-another-planet/265138#265138)

Comment: Not seeing any covers looking like an Apollo capsule on [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/64007) though.

Comment: While throwing the book against the wall would be satisfying, composting it would be better by denying someone the opportunity of reading it in the future.

Comment: Was the crew "modified"? All I remember of that aspect is them being frozen on Titan and re-animated by some far future civilization that arises.
Earth politics started the disaster in the book, US Super-Fundamentalists, and I think a (cold?) war with China, results in China using a neutron bomb on an asteroid to beat the US, only to destroy the whole Earth.

Comment: @Nick I didn't get that far. If you have another book in mind where a guy in an X-15 tried to shoot down a space shuttle, please post it as an answer.